# Dynamics CRM vs SQL 2017 vs Server 2016

Tags: database, sql-server, dynamics-crm

We have a Windows Server 2016 installation which hosted CRM 2016 v8.0 and SQL 2012, a few months ago I upgraded SQL 2012 to SQL 2017 and CRM 2016 v8.2 without realizing the fact that the Dynamics Reporting Extension does not work with SQL 2017.

Its been a few months since then, even after the release of v9.0 Microsoft has not added support for SQL 2017
Now we are stuck where we are and we cannot do any upgrades or change our environment. we do not have an older backup prior to SQL 2017.

I've tried installing Windows Server 2016 & SQL 2016 SP2 along with Dynamics CRM v9.0 on a new VM but i am unable to restore 2017 version of the CRM database. I've tried "Generate Scripts" but the file is too large to open (2.08Gb) in management studio or anywhere else, If i export data & schema's per file I get a lot of errors importing items and the final Import fails in CRM.

I've tried to Install SQL 2016 SP2 for Report server & Reporting Extension along side with SQL 2017 as a separate instance, but here when i try to import the organization in CRM i get error 'could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.smo' 
Problem here is that even though Sql management objects has been installed in SQL Server 2016, in 2017 its not available as a feature pack install instead its part of Visual Studio NuGet Package.

I believe i've tried almost everything I can in the past 2 days but I am hoping there is a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out.

In the logs it said `could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.smo version=11.0.0.0`

So I followed the below post from another user to download and install SQL Management Objects for SQL Server 2012 and I was able to import the Organization.
[Read Iman Mahmoudinasab Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)